# Calculating the centroid from points in a MySQL-table

Tags: mysql, geospatial, centroid

In a MySQL-table I have a column of the "point" geospatial datatype. Is it posssible to calculate the centroid of all the point-values of all rows directly in MySQL?

The aim of my project is to put the center of a map at the centroid of the points that it contains.

One potential solution is given in the MySQL documentation: [Centroid(mpoly)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/geometry-property-functions.html#function_centroid). But this would mean that I had to concatenate all points' values externally in a programming language and then send the resulting query back to MySQL. This sounds quirky to me.

Answer (score 0):

A centroid is simply the intersection of the mean X and Y values, so the following should work:

```
SELECT
    POINT( AVG(X(geographic_location)), AVG(Y(geographic_location)) )
FROM poles
```